# How to calculate the size of the video based on given chroma information?

Tags: video, numeric, filesize, subsampling

I was asked in the test on what will be the size of the video of 10 seconds displayed at 25fps assuming each chroma sample takes 4 bits, luminance component takes 8 bits and 4:2:0 chroma sampling is used in image object of 32x32 pixels?

This was my solution: 10 x 25 x (8 x 2) x (8 x 4) x 32 x 32

Was my solution correct? If not how could it be rectified?

Comment: Where does the 25, and the 2 come from?

Comment: @szatmary Sorry, mistyped question, fixed it. 25 is FPS and 2 is from 4:"2":0

Comment: Please correct the question to fix the type-o. Also, did you read the wikipedia on a [Chrome subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#4:2:0)

Comment: Me and @szatmary had an argument about the correctness of my answer. Please let us know the right answer, after you get the results of your exam (and also the accurate question if possible).

Comment: @Rotem acknowledged. I will do it once I get the results...

Comment: @Rotem it turns out my answer was correct, now I am not totally sure whether my professor concept was right or not but that's how it went

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your answer is wrong!

YUV420 format means that each 2x2 pixels has 2 chroma components (one `U` and one `V`),  and 4 lumma components.

List of components of 2x2 pixels (4 pixels):
4 `Y` Elements
1 `U` Element
1 `V` Element

A drawing may help you count:

```
Y     Y
  U,V  
Y     Y
```

Size of Y (lumma) data size in bits is:
`10 x 25 x 32 x 32 x 8` = `2048000` bits

Size of U chroma data size in bits is:
`(10 x 25 x 32 x 32 x 4)/4` = `256000` bits (we need to divide by 4, because each 4 pixels has only one `U` element).

Size of V chroma data size in bits is the same a U: `256000` bits

Total size in bits:
`10 x 25 x 32 x 32 x 8` + `2 x (10 x 25 x 32 x 32 x 4)/4` = `2560000` bits.

Most of the time size is measured in **bytes** (not in bits).
Size in bytes is `2560000 / 8` = `320000` Bytes.

---

Other way to look at the problem is computing the average bits per pixel:
Each pixel has a Y element (8 bits).

Each 4 pixels have 1 U (4 bits) and 1 V (4 bits)
8 bits per 4 pixels, gives an average of 2 bits per pixel for chroma.

Average: **10 bits per pixel**.

Total size in bits:  `10 x 25 x 32 x 32 x 10` = `2560000` bits = `320000` Bytes.

Comment: Except yuv420 is 12 bits per pixel (8 + 2 × 8/4)

Comment: @szatmary in the most common format, YUV420 is 12 bits per pixel (when Y, U,V are all 8 bits), but in the question, it is given: **"each chroma sample takes 4 bits"**, so the there are only 10 bits per pixel...

Comment: 8+4 = 12. OP means U+V = 4 bits per pixel. Not 4 for U and 4 for V. That would be 4:2:2

Comment: @szatmary As I understand it "each chroma sample takes 4 bits", means 4 for U and 4 for V. Instead of common 4:2:0 format where there are 8 for U and 8 for V, in our case there are only 4 for U and 4 for V.

Comment: We have to read between the lines a bit. OP is a little confused, and not really sure how subsampling works. It’s way more likely that they meant 2+2=4 than dealing with a non standard hybrid 4:2:2/4:2:0 format.

Comment: @szatmary I am not talking about hybrid 4:2:2/4:2:0, I am talking about 4:2:0, where there are only 4 bits for U and 4 bits for V (instead of the familiar 8 for U and 8 for V as you know it). You do agree that in the familiar 4:2:0 there are 8 bits for U and 8 for V right? And an average of 12 bits per pixel right?

Comment: In a single pixel? No that’s wrong. There are 8 luma bits, 2 Cr, 2 Cb. 8/8/8 would be 4:4:4 (8+8+8 does not equal 12)

Comment: @szatmary 8 for U and 8 for V, but each such `U,V` are common to 4 pixels.

Comment: I see where your coming from. But I still believe that it is more likely that OP had a bit of ambiguity in the question than they have a file with 4 bits of color. I don’t even think there is a 4cc code for that.

Comment: @szatmary an average of 4 bits of color information per pixel is the most common 4:2:0 format. It **"was asked in the test"**, so I assumed it's a little tricky (I had to assume the teacher gave non-standard example for academic purposes). It is possible that I was wrong.

Comment: Lol. You keep switching back and forth between storage bits per pixel and display bit per pixel and assuming I’m wrong, and I keep switching to try to match your switching. Also, I am 99% sure this was not a trick question.

Comment: @szatmary I am sorry for my inconsistencies, and there is a good chance that you are right (I read the question carefully and still not convinced). I think **Each 4 pixels have 1 U (4 bits) and 1 V (4 bits)** is a valid assumption.